# Starting Udev hangs at boot

Tags: boot, rhel

We have One SuperMicro server and on that we installed RHEL 5.6 64 bit but after installation it hangs at STARTING UDEV .

Any ideas what is stopping it to start and proceed.

[image: Boot]

Comment: Try starting in single user mode. See [link](http://support.foray.com/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=64)

Comment: Once you get into single user mode check the messages log for errors that might be causing the issue, then update your question with any pertinent information

Comment: @midnightsteel ok dear I will try this on Saturday coz tomorrow is off and after checking the errors i will update my question. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `quiet` from the kernel command line and you should get enough output to see the cause of the hang.

Comment: Yes I did this but there was some issue with one RAM so i removed all RAMs i plugged them and tested them one at a time and it solve the problem by removing the defected one

Comment: @Jim Paris Very helpful tip -- this led me to discover the BMC unit on the mobo was the cause of the boot delay.